# This command is not available because no document is opened

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am relatively new to mailmerge. I tried to implement this code for an action button in order to implement mail merge but i keep getting error as stated in the subject with this line `With ActiveDocument.MailMerge` being highlighed with yellow

I have looked at my word template and nothing seems to be wrong.

```
Private Sub Command30_Click()
   'set variables
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oWdoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdInputName As String
    Dim wdOutputName As String
    Dim outFileName As String

' Set Template Path
    '------------------------------------------------
    wdInputName = CurrentProject.Path & "X:\PM\PM-O\PM-OQ\PM-OQRA\PROCESSES\03_Pigments\98_ Database\05_Inventory\02_Bulk_letter\word_template.docx"

 ' Create unique save filename with minutes
    ' and seconds to prevent overwrite
    '------------------------------------------------
    outFileName = "Merck_InvStatements_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddmms")

 ' Output File Path w/outFileName
    '------------------------------------------------
    wdOutputName = CurrentProject.Path & "\desktop\completed\" & outFileName

     Set oWord = New Word.Application
    Set oWdoc = oWord.Documents.Open(wdInputName)

    ' Start mail merge
    '------------------------------------------------
    With oWord

    oWord.Visible = True
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        .OpenDataSource _
            Name:=CurrentProject.FullName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            LinkToSource:=True, _
            Connection:="Q_SERIAL_INVENTORY_A02", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Q_SERIAL_INVENTORY_A02]"
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
   End With
 ' Hide Word During Merge
    '------------------------------------------------
    oWord.Visible = False

    ' Save file as PDF
    ' Uncomment the line below and comment out
    ' the line below "Save file as Word Document"
    '------------------------------------------------
    'oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 wdOutputName & ".pdf", 17

    ' Save file as Word Document
    '------------------------------------------------
    oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 wdOutputName & ".docx", 16

    ' Quit Word to Save Memory
    '------------------------------------------------
    oWord.Quit savechanges:=False

    ' Clean up memory
    '------------------------------------------------
    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oWdoc = Nothing
     End Sub`
```

Comment: instead of ```with activedocument.mailmerge``` try ```with owdoc.mailmerge``` I don't think owdoc is active.

Comment: Why are you using `ActiveDocument` instead of `oWdoc` - throughout the code?

Comment: hi. this doesnt make sense "CurrentProject.Path & "X:\PM\PM-O\PM-OQ\PM-OQRA\PROCESSES\03_Pigments\98_ Database\05_Inventory\02_Bulk_letter\word_template.docx". leave just te "X:\...." and delete the CurrentProject.Path

Comment: I have edited the code as suggested but the error as changed to "The is not a valid file name" and it colours  `oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 wdOutputName & ".docx", 16` as yellow. I tried to remove the `activedocument` but the error changed to method or data member not found

Comment: whats the value of wdOutputName ?

Comment: `OutFileName` is lacking a file extension, such as docx.

Comment: Not source of error but need to use `nn` for minutes `yyyymmddnnss`.

Comment: is this word ? i believe that CurrentProject.Path  is from access. in word is document.path i believe

Comment: Let me once again clarify more the problem for easier understanding 1.There is an existing macro-enabled word template that is perfectle working 2. but i will have to click on the word in order to run it,(i didnt know who designed it). 3. now I want to be running it by clicking a button on a form 4.so I am trying to adapt the macro in the word to the `on click event` of the button. 5. i have tried to erase the macro from the word (though i still have it somewhere) 6. Like i said, my experience is low 7. I need serious help in this as I am on a borrowed time about this project already

Comment: This line: `Set oWdoc = oWord.Documents.Open(wdInputName)`: Write in the correct path, manually, for testing purposes. Does that work? If it does, start checking each part of the code that builds `wdInputName` until you find where the error is. Given the information in the question and your lack of experience, that's the only way. You have to **learn** how to track these things down.